# Using recursion to find subsequences

Tags: python, recursion

I need a program to return `True` if one string (`s2`) can be turned into another string (`s1`) only by removing characters from `s2`. So for example if `s1 = star` and `s2 = swewtffsafefr` it would return `True`

I've come up with this so far:

```
def subsequence(s1, s2, pos=0):
    if pos < len(s1):
        subsequence(s1,s2, pos+1)
    else:
        return 0
```

I can't figure out how to make it remove characters in `s2` that aren't in `s1`

Comment: what are you doing with this code ... can you explain in english what you want to accomplish? (step by step)

Comment: This code here is as far as I got, I want to give two arguments to the function, `s1` and `s2`, they are both strings. I want to use recursion to go through each position character in `s2` and return `True` if `s2` can be made equal to `s1` my removing 0 or more characters from it

Comment: there I gave a very thorough answer to a simple question ... hopefully you can do it on the test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so you know you want a recursive function `subseq(s1,s2)`

first you need to come up with your basecases

1. s1 == s2  , for this we will return true
2. s1 is empty , for this we will also return true
3. s2 is empty but s1 is not, we will return false
4. everything else

next you need to put that into code

1. `if s1 in s2:return True`
2. `if not s1: return True`
3. `if not s2: return False`
4. `#everything else`

for everything else we need to break it down further

1. if s1[0] == s2[0] advance both pointers
2. otherwise only advance s2

.

```
def subseq(s1,s2):
    if s1 in s2: return True
    if not s1: return True
    if not s2: return False
    #everything else
    if s1[0] == s2[0]: return subseq(s1[1:],s2[1:])
    return subseq(s1,s2[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove chars in s2 that are not in s1 is not hard, there are a number of approaches

```
set_s1 = set([item for item in s1])
set_s2 = set([item for item in s2])
```

This gets you the unique  characters in s1 and s2

Now to identify the values in s2 not in s1

```
diff = set_s2.difference(set_s1)
```

Now to remove the characters from s2 in the diff (those in s2 not in s1)

```
if len(diff) == 0:
    break
else:
    new_s2 = ''
    for c in s2:
        if c not in diff:
            new_s2 = new_s2 + c
```

Problem you still have is removing duplicates